# Unable to change min_decryption_version to 0

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have a requirement to create key in hashicorp, and change its min_decryption_version to 0. Key generation is successful, and the values are as below.

```
"latest_version": 2,
"min_available_version": 0,
"min_decryption_version": 1,
"min_encryption_version": 0,
```

I have tried to change min_decryption_version using *transit/keys/mykey/config* API. I am able to change the version to 2. When I change it to 0, the request is successful,but the values are not reflected in the key.
Is there any other pre-condition that needs to be satisfied before changing the min_decryption_version?

Comment: So to clarify what you're saying: you can change the value between 1 and 2 and back again successfully, but if you try to set it to 0 instead it doesn't work?

Comment: yes, you are correct. I can change from 1 to 2, and 2 to 1, but not to 0.

Comment: Just a sanity check - you're not accidentally trying to set `min_decryption_value`, instead of `min_decryption_version`? I ask because you've used that incorrect name in the question.

Comment: Also, I don't suppose you've done a "trim" operation, deleting your key zero? (https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/transit#trim-key)

Comment: Hi, it is min_decryption_version. I have corrected the question. Also, I don't do trim operation. I have noticed the generated keys start with 1 (key 1). Could it be the reason the min_decryption_version can't be set to 0?

Comment: Seems like that could be the case. And even if not, if you don't have any keys below 1, then a minimum of 1 should be fine?

Comment: I think should be ok